# Как программно сделать что бы гаджет не тушил экран на странице веб-приложения

Tags: android, jquery, python-3.x, webbrowser

Экран устройства должен быть постоянно включен когда в браузере открыт сайт моего веб-приложения (веб-приложение написано на Python3 + Flask), как-то можно реализовать это программно? Как "сказать" телефону, что не надо тушить свет?
Как это например с воспроизведением видео работает?

При разворачивании на полный экран блока `body`, при помощи jquery.fullscreen устройство все равно переходит в спящий режим почему то.

Comment: Через фуллскрин апи

Comment: @eri спасибо засовет! сейчас использовал библиотеку jqueri.fullscreen но при переходе в полноэеранный режим экран все равно тухнет и еще в довесок пропадает background хотя при использовании F11 он не пропадает. Подскажете что нибудь?